# Batch file: environment variable "if" string test

Tags: command-line, batch, environment-variables

In a batch file, I'm calling another batch file to set a number of date environment variables.

The data variables set properly and I can call them.

However, in this instance, I need to compare two of these environment variables and determine if they are the same in order to conditionally launch the rest of the batch (or skip to end/exit).

However, I cannot seem to get the conditional to execute the test (comparison) of the two environment variables.

These are defined as %today2% (today's date set as MMDDYY) and %firstmonday%, which is a calculated first Monday of the month and set as MMYYDD). When run today (October 14, 2015), these return 101415 and 110215.

I am then attempting to test these in the following way:

```
if %today2%==%firstmonday% goto GO else END
```

However, the test seems to be completely ignored -- the test always proceeds to GO regardless.

If I `echo %today%` and `%firstmonday%` they are of course different, but somehow the test evaluates to true and executes.

If I'm not explaining myself clearly, please let me know and I'll try to do a better job of it. I'm rather a novice when it comes to this, but have mucked around with it for a while and cannot seem to figure out the logic flaw.

Comment: If you type `if /?` it gives examples of the correct syntax when there is an `else` clause: indeed it gives your example as an instance of a command that does NOT work, together with two working versions. Because the `else` syntax is inelegant, I find it easier to reverse the test, as in `if not %today2%==%firstmonday% goto END`, with the following line as the `GO` code.

Comment: You have to `..else goto END` and have `:END` after your `:GO` marker, as it currently just going to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

I've created two batch files: `b1.cmd` and `b2.cmd` which follow. First, `b2.cmd` which sets your variables as described:

```
set today2=101415
set firstmonday=110215
```

Then `b1.cmd` which performs as desired:

```
@echo off
call b2.cmd
echo today=%today2%
echo firstmonday=%firstmonday%
if "%today2%"=="%firstmonday%" (
    goto go
) else (
    goto end
)
:go
echo at go
goto :EOF
:end
echo at end
```